# higher weak derivatives of the hat function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

The hat function is defined as:
$$
\phi(x) = (1-|x|)_{+}
$$
where $(y)_{+} = \max\{y, 0\}$. I know that the hat function is a member of the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(-1, 1)$ for $p \in [1, \infty]$. The question is: $\phi(x) \in W^{k, p}(-1, 1)$? for $k > 1$ and $ p \in [1, \infty]$.

Comment: If you look at the (weak) derivative $\phi'$, you should be able to see that the next (distributional) derivative $\phi''$ includes Dirac deltas, and hence it's not representable by an integrable function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The key word is Sobolev Embedding. In fact in dimension $ 1 $, it implies that if
$$ k-\frac{1}{p} > 1 $$
then $ W^{k,p}(-1,1) \subset C^1 $.

The answer to your question is than $ \phi $ is in $ W^{k,p} $ if
$$ k-\frac{1}{p} < 1. $$
If $ k \in \mathbb{N} $, we proved for $ k \in \mathbb{R} $ you need an extra argument.